# How to have multiline keyword documentation in log.html

Tags: robotframework

If in a keyword you have the following:

```
[Documentation]     First line
...                 Second line
...                 Third line
```

the HTML log shows "First line Second line Third line"

Is it possibile to have the HTML log show the multiline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
[Documentation]     First line${\n}
...                 Second line${\n}
...                 Third line
```

Let me know :)

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Robot Framework 4.0 and possiblly with previous versions as well.

Comment: @beforesunset Consider accepting this answer if it has worked for you.

Comment: This works for test case documentation, but not for keyword documentation unexpectedly. Tested both on RF 3.2.2 and 4.0.